# How to create a custom region in gnome3?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, locale

Gnome3 doesn't include my region. I need:

- calendar week to start on monday
- british-english spelling
- 8.5x11 as the default document size for printing
- celsius for temperatures
- miles for distances
- currency in dollars
- etc etc etc

How can I make this happen?

My thought is, make a new region. Or modify an existing region. But I can't find the documentation for this.

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: you may want this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/SC22/WG20/docs/n972-14652ft.pdf (Information technology —
Specification method for cultural
conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Locale setting is not a function of the GNOME3 desktop. You need to set your locale in your Operating System. `man locale`.